# What is the proper dependency entry in pom.xml to use the Snowball analyzer with Lucene 2.4.0?

Tags: maven-2, lucene, snowballanalyzer

I'm trying to swap in the [SnowballAnalyzer](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/api/org/apache/lucene/analysis/snowball/SnowballAnalyzer.html) for [StandardAnalyzer](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/api/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardAnalyzer.html) on my Maven 2 project. I'm currently using

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-contrib</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

but I keep getting the following error:

```
Missing:
----------
1) org.apache.lucene:lucene-contrib:jar:2.4.0
```

Comment: I swear that says, "porn.xml".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the repos it looks like you should be including this one:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
   <artifactId>lucene-snowball</artifactId>
   <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

At least from what I can see from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ that looks like the proper dependency ?